# array works fine but audio not starting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I declared three variables and put those into array when, First audio starts fine but when I click `.next` button it consoles `trench2` variable but still restarts the first audio if I click `.next` again it consoles `trench3` but plays `trench2`. Can you help me to fix this and instead of playing first `trench` twice go to `trench2` and `trench3` correctly.

```
var playthis = new Audio();
var trench1 = 'songs/Chlorine.m4a';
var trench2 = 'songs/Astrix.mp3';
var trench3 = 'songs/dro.mp3';
var trenches = [trench1,trench2,trench3];
var current_trench = 0;   
playthis.src = trenches[current_trench];             
$('.next').click(function(){
    playthis.pause();
    playthis.src = trenches[current_trench++];
    console.log(trenches[current_trench]);
    playthis.play();
}
```

```html
<button class="next"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`current_trench++` returns the current value of current_trench and then increments it.
What you want to use is `++current_trench` which increments first and then returns the incremented value.

```
playthis.src = trenches[++current_trench];
```